# How to use Blur event for AppState in react native

Tags: react-native

Please I need an example on how to use the 'blur' event for react native AppState. I am trying to respond to when the app is not in focus e.g. when the user pulls the notification drawer but I keep getting the error message `Invariant Violation: Trying to subscribe to unknown event: "blur"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the tags associated with the commit that this feature landed in (https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/d45818fe47c53a670db933cf805910e227aa79c9) it seems like that is only available starting in 0.61 and hasn't landed in a stable release yet. Make sure you're running 0.61.0-rc.0 or later.

Comment: Thanks @azundo. I am currently running RN version 0.59.10

Comment: @chukwuma-nwaugha Did you find a solution to handle this? I am running react-native v0.59.8 and facing similar challenges.

Comment: Hi @KeshavSharma, it appears this feature is available only on RN0.61. Please see the accepted answer. Thanks

Comment: @chukwuma-nwaugha I get that it will be available in RN0.61. I wanted to know if you were able to handle notification drawers pull in RN 0.59.10?

Comment: Not yet @KeshavSharma, none of the approaches I tried worked.

Answer (score 2):

**According to [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/appstate) . Blur is [Android only]**

"[Android only] Received when the user is not actively interacting with the app. Useful in situations when the user pulls down the notification drawer. AppState won't change but the blur event will get fired."

**if you still want to use it for android you can use it with condition for android only**

```
import { Platform } from "react-native";

........

 componentDidMount() {
    if (Platform.OS === "android") {
      AppState.addEventListener("blur", this._handleAppStateBlur);
    }
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    if (Platform.OS === "android") {
      AppState.removeEventListener("blur", this._handleAppStateBlur);
    }
  }

  _handleAppStateBlur = () => {
    console.log("blur");
  };
```

Comment: Thanks @MehranKhan, but I tried this approach already and I got the error: `Invariant Violation: Trying to subscribe to unknown event: "blur"`. I think @azundo's comment explains this.

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs mentioned in the official react native documentation, there are three states supported by [AppState](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/appstate#docsNav):

> **active** - The app is running in the foreground.
>
> **background** - The app is running in the background. The user is either:
>   in another app
>   on the home screen
>   [Android] on another Activity (even if it was launched by your app)
>
> **[iOS] inactive** - This is a state that occurs when transitioning between foreground & background, and during periods of inactivity such as entering the Multitasking view or in the event of an incoming call.

Since there is no such state as **blur**, therefore you are facing an error saying that it could not find such event.

**Edit**

You have to register **blur** as an event in your component lifecycle, but you have to be cautious here and have to determine the Platform before registering **blur** event as it is available in android only and not in ios.

To register an event you have to do this:

```
import React from 'react';
import {AppState} from 'react-native';
class HandlingEvents extends React.Pure.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        // your state goes here...
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        // your event will be registered here, when your component is mounted on // the screen. 
        // Be cautious here, make a platform check here so as to avoid discrepancies in ios devices
        AppState.addEventListener('blur',this.handleBlurState)
    }
    componentWillUnMount() {
        // your event will be removed here, when your component gets unmounted from the screen.
        // Be cautious here, make a platform check here so as to avoid discrepancies in ios devices
        AppState.removeEventListener('blur',this.handleBlurState)
    }
    handleBlurState = (nextAppState) => {
        //this method will contain your entire logic, as to how you want to treat your component in this event.
        // As per the docs, since the state of your app will not changed, therefore you can continue your logic here by checking if the state of your app is **change** or not..
        if (AppState.currentState === "active" && nextAppState === "active") {
            //whatever task you want to perform here..;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Anus Kaleem, please understand what I mean. I said `event` not `state`. There are three events listed on the page `change`, `focus` and `blur`. The common one is `change`, but I want to use `blur` as the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/appstate#events) described

Comment: Thanks @AnusKaleem! @azondo's comment explains what the challenge is.